# previous item from collection using each helper

Tags: ember.js

I'm using the each helper and need access to the previous item.

```
{{#each item in items}}
  {{previous}}
{{/each}}
```

How can I get the previous item?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the new form of the each helper which gives you the index and passed this along with the items into a component which then calculates the previous item.

```
{{#each items as |item index|}}
  {{some-component item=item index=index collection=items}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Would be interested to know if there's a slicker way to do it. Maybe we could add previous to the each helper :)

Comment: I think this is a good solution. If `item` is a model and belongsTo some parent, you could add a computed property that looks up the previous item directly to the model